# How to store larger JSON data in LocalStorage and Sqlite storage in Cordova based iOS app without having performance issues

Tags: ios, json, sqlite, cordova

I want to store large amount of JSON data in Local Storage as well as SQLiteDb , currently I am using JSON.stringify which is causing performance issue. How can we over come this ?

Comment: Where does the data come from? If you need it from the beginning, you can use a precompiled db. Otherwise you should use webworkers, For both issues, have a look here: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Comment: User is going to input the data. I am already using SQLITE plugin but having problem when i have to stringify the JSON data so that i can store it in DB. App abnormally crashes due to this